# Await is not accepted while function is defined as async

Tags: sqlite, flutter

I have an error message about an asynchronous function. I use await and my function is well defined as asynchronous. To be more specific, the error refers to the last line of my code (when I call function getObjects() ).

My code is mainly based on the documentation, so I'm quite surprise to face an error.

Error message:

```
{
    "resource": "/Users/MyName/Documents/Development/thesafe1/lib/main.dart",
    "owner": "dart",
    "code": "await_in_wrong_context",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The await expression can only be used in an async function.\nTry marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'.",
    "source": "dart",
    "startLineNumber": 52,
    "startColumn": 31,
    "endLineNumber": 52,
    "endColumn": 36,
    "tags": []
}
```

My code:

```
//Open database
final Future<Database> database = getDatabasesPath().then((String path) {
  return openDatabase(join(path, 'database.db'), onCreate: (db, version) {
    return db.execute(
        //"CREATE TABLE objects(uuid TEXT PRIMARY KEY, objectName TEXT, price REAL, category TEXT"
        "CREATE TABLE objects(uuid TEXT PRIMARY KEY, objectName TEXT)"
      );
  }, version: 1);
});

//Functions to access the database of objects : insert, get
//Function to insert object in the database
Future<void> insertObject(MyObject object) async {
  final Database db = await database;

  await db.insert('objects', object.toMap(),
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace);
}

Future<List<MyObject>> getObjects() async {
  final Database db = await database;

  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('objects');

  return List.generate(maps.length, (i){
    return MyObject(
      uuid: maps[i]['uuid'],
      objectName: maps[i]['objectName']
    );
  });
}

List<MyObject> myObjectList = await getObjects();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use all method as following description:

1. You've to write all methods inside the singleton class. (I've taken **FireBaseModel**)
2. You can use that function in **StateFul** Widget as below.

   ```
       @override void initState() {   
       super.initState(); 
       var allObjects = FireBaseModel.instance. getObjects();
       if (allObjects != null) {
         setState(() {
           refreshUI();
         });
       }
     }
   ```

**How to create singleton instance:**

```
class FireBaseModel  {
  FireBaseModel._privateConstructor() {
    debugPrint('constructor');
  }

  static final FireBaseModel _instance =
      FireBaseModel._privateConstructor();

  // Singleton object
  static FireBaseModel get instance {
    return _instance;
  }

   //
   .
   .
   .
   Add all your methods here

}
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. How does it help for the function be consider async, as she is defined?

Comment: @DescampsAu check the answer. I've update the answer. As per you question I the post the answer. How you can use the your code.